# Could I request paternity leave while I am on two weeks notice?

Tags: united-states, resignation, benefits, parental-leave

I found a job out of state (east coast USA), and it starts January 19. Due to the complications of moving and also family obligations, I can't really work effectively during the normal two-week notice period.

I have been at my firm  as a consultant for 8 years already, and was told by a friend that I could simply take the paternity leave and quit during that time. This way I would be able to actually move and settle in my new state, and then give notice.

Or do you think I should work this out with my manager? I do not want to burn bridges, or at least minimize the damage. But I need the money, and don't want to have a 2 or 3 week gap in pay either

Comment: What country/state are you in?

Comment: In the USA , and moving to Maryland f/ the south

Comment: It usually takes time to apply for parental leave and get it approved. My guess is it probably takes longer than 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the timing?  Has your child been born yet?  When is the due date?

Comment: @Kevin - yes child has been born already.. in fact she's 7 months. But I had not used all my paternity leave I am entitled to (although I wonder if things would change if I put in notice)

Comment: "I do not want to burn bridges"  Why?  IF it is completely within the rules, why wouldn't you do this?  Do you think a company would worry about "burning bridges" with you in any action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest issue may be healthcare.

If the mother/child are depending on your healthcare though your employer you need to understand what happens when you turn-in your notice. Some end your coverage at the end of the notice period, some go to the end of the month, others could say today is your last day.

You also need to understand how to new company will cover you. Some cover you on day one, others make you wait to the start of the next month.

Keep in mind that if you move then quit, you might run into an issue if you have to return a laptop, phone, other company equipment.

> Or do you think I should work this out with my manager? I do not want
> to burn bridges, or at least minimize the damage. But I need the
> money, and don't want to have a 2 or 3 week gap in pay either

Normally a person in the US gives notice, and then spends the next two weeks cleaning up projects and preparing to handover information. Your plan to quit, but not be there to help, will burn-bridges. You won't be the first to do this. I have seen it done a couple of times, and nobody is ever happy about it.

Based on a comment you made:

> yes child has been born already.. in fact she's 7 months. But I had
> not used all my paternity leave I am entitled to (although I wonder if
> things would change if I put in notice).

Management generally doesn't like it when a departing employee takes leave during their notice period. It makes it very hard to have a successful turnover. Even if you can get them to approve paternity leave quickly, they may decide that the moment you start your paternity leave you are no longer an employee because you will not be able to help them.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this doesn't actually answer the OP's question.  OP is asking how to interact with the boss so as not to burn bridges.

Answer (score 6):

> Could I request paternity leave while I am on two weeks notice?

You can, but it most likely will not go over well.  It will be difficult to justify taking paternal leave 7 months after your baby was born without it looking odd (even though you may be legally entitled to do so).  Top that off with your plan to resign while on paternal leave and you will definitely burn bridges.

The best approach would be to forget about the paternal leave and speak to your boss and explain the situation.  Maybe your boss is reasonable and will try to accommodate for your situation.  This is the approach that will result in the least damage.

Comment: Thanks I am leaning to calling my boss and explaining the whole situation. We have been on good terms lately , and I can add much more detail about it.

Comment: +1 - this is the answer I was going to type out after I saw the '7 months' comment.  My immediate reaction was, "Yeah, they're going to realize you were just gaming the system and left us in the dark on purpose."

Answer (score 1):

> Could I request paternity leave while I am on two weeks notice?

Yes, you can request paternity leave. Only your employer can tell you if it will be granted or not. Almost certainly there is a written HR policy regarding resignation while on leave of any kind.

I'm guessing the answer is "No", but only a formal will get you the answer you are seeking.

If you are on very good terms with your boss, you could ask their opinion first, before going to HR with the formal request.